# Firewall questions about state and policy?

Tags: iptables, linux, rules

I finally managed to install my VM host and now I am messing with iptables to create, test and learn.

1. Does it matter if i put the below
   rules at the begin or at the end of
   my rules ?

   ```
   $IPT -P INPUT DROP
   $IPT -P FORWARD DROP
   $IPT -P OUTPUT DROP
   ```

   i have tested and there was no difference but i would like to confirm.

   **Answer I choose so far:**
   It is a good idea to apply your policies as early as possible. Put them at the start. DROP rules on internal traffic can cause problems.
2. Having the below rule would be considered as a fault on the firewall ?

   ```
   $IPT -A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
   ```

   Without this rule i would need to add for example an OUTPUT rule for my ssh connection, example:

   ```
   $IPT -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 2013 -j ACCEPT
   ```

   **Answer:**
   After more tests and talks with people on #iptables@freenode, i came to the conclusion that using `-m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT` for INPUT and OUPUT is a fine approch and will help you deal with lots of things like for example the FTP and is a fine approch because unless you have that given port open and being accept there will be no malicious connection on it.

   Here is a normal example without using the above:

   ```
   $IPT -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 20:21 -j ACCEPT
   $IPT -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 20:21 -j ACCEPT
   ```

   Now here is how the rule looks like using the above:

   ```
   $IPT -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 21 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
   ```

   That's all you need because once the connection is ESTABLISHED, the output will follow-up right away and you won't need to make rules for the ftp-data port.
3. What are bad things of having the below rule, could you give some example as to why not have it and instead just define anything you may need to use ?

   ```
   $IPT -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
   ```

   **Answer I choose so far:**
   This policy rule allows all outgoing traffic. As a policy, allowing everything is obviously less secure than allowing only explicit kinds of traffic. So if security is your utmost priority, you'll want to set a DROP policy on the output chain instead. Just be aware that you'll then have to include a number of rules to allow outgoing traffic to a possibly large number of mundane things, such as: DNS, SMTP, IMAP, POP3, HTTP, HTTPS, etc.
4. What is the difference between conntrack and state in the below context ?

   state example:

   ```
   $IPT -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
   ```

   conntrack example:

   ```
   $IPT -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
   ```

   **Answer:**
   After some research talks with people on #iptables@freenode i came to the conclusion i should be using conntrack from here on.

   > Technically the conntrack match
   >   supersedes - and so obsoletes - the
   >   state  match. But practically the
   >   state match is not obsoleted in any
   >   way.

---

***I would aswell appreciate good online iptables reading materials.***

---

### **Links recommended so far:**

[Perfect Ruleset](http://jengelh.medozas.de/documents/Perfect_Ruleset.pdf)

[The Linux Documentation Project](http://tldp.org/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It is a good idea to apply your policies as early as possible.  Put them at the start.  DROP rules on internal traffic can cause problems.
2. This rule would be consideref a fault, as it implements and ACCEPT policy.  Adding an accept rule per service is the correct way to build your firewall.
3. An accept policy indicates you are running a mostly open policy.  (We locked the front door locked, but you can use any other door to get in.) Best policy is a mostly closed policy.  We keep all door and windows locked, and only unlock the ones we need.
4. It would appear there is no difference, although all the rules I have seen use state.  The conctrack module will monitor the state.  Use this rule with the port accept rule in question 2 to enable services.

You may want to look at the [Shorewall](http://shorewall.net/) documentation to see what can be done with iptables.  I use it to build a firewall on all my Linux instances (including OpenWRT). It has well documented sample (default/base) configurations for servers with 1, 2 or 3 interfaces.

[The Linux Documentation Project](http://tldp.org/) also has documentation.

Comment: about your answer on 2 that is what i was thinking about it. So having an open state rule like that wether on the INPUT OR OUTPUT indeed does allow any requests to any services i have available and would be more suitable if i do it those per rule ?

Comment: +1 Thanks for the links while i am not planning on using any softwares (i will take a look at the docs from shoreall) on top of my iptables most because i want to learn on it and not on tools that goes on top of it.

Comment: something just crossed my mind, you can use `ptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED` without pointing it to ACCEPT would that be the same as declaring it on all rules in place on the rules list ?

Comment: @Guapo I believe you need to point the rule at ACCEPT.  This should be an early rule as it is intended to bypass rule processing for connections which habe been accepted, and are being tracked.  The RELATED portion allows FTP connections and other protocols which use multiple ports.  These are handled by protocol specific modules such as ns_conntract_ftp.

Comment: yes i figured that out after some more tests but thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention anything about the **nat** table, so I'm going to assume that this question relates to writing iptables firewall scripts for standalone servers, and not for multi-homed/gateway boxes.

1. You are correct: Each chain has a single policy, so it doesn't matter where or in what order that policy rules are stated.
2. This rule establishes a convention that many/most firewall scripts use: that of **statefulness**. Just a minor nitpick, though. I would not include the NEW state, and I would also include a rule for the INPUT chain, i.e.:

   `$IPT -A INPUT  -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT`

   `$IPT -A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT`

   I put these rules near or at the top of all of my firewall scripts, as they allow me to concentrate on creating rules for filtering connection attempts, and not have to think about non-connection-establishing packets. In my opinion, a firewall script without these rules is likely to be more complicated, and thus more prone to mistakes, than one that includes them.
3. This policy rule allows all outgoing traffic. As a policy, allowing everything is obviously less secure than allowing only explicit kinds of traffic. So if security is your utmost priority, you'll want to set a DROP policy on the output chain instead. Just be aware that you'll then have to include a number of rules to allow outgoing traffic to a possibly large number of mundane things, such as: DNS, SMTP, IMAP, POP3, HTTP, HTTPS, etc.

Comment: `You didn't mention anything about the nat table` thanks for point that out but i am doing the questions as i face them so i am yet to get to the nat part currently i am learning OUTPUT INPUT FORWARD then i will move to nat and mangle. i've made a VM just to learn those so dont worry we will get there :) about Q2 i do have one for INPUT without the NEW ofc but i was just wondering about the output one since that is more related to inner stuff i mean if you can't stablish a IN connection there will be no OUT connection ssh as for example.

Comment: About Q3 i do realise that ;) and i prefer it as DROP, also there is Q4 :) if u know about it let me know.

Comment: Just to tell a little more about the Q2 from the test i did, having only `$IPT -A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT` i don't even need `$IPT -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 2013 -j ACCEPT` as it already seem to understand that it is an stablished OUTPUT from an known INPUT

Comment: Oh yes, I missed Q4. I think BillThor covered that pretty well. As for iptables docs, the `man iptables` is quite comprehensive :) .

Answer (score 0):

State vs. Conntrack:  State was removed in favor of conntrack effective with Linux kernel 3.7

Comment: This isn't an answer and should be posted as a comment to the question.

Comment: Well, it is hard for soemone without enough rep to post a comment, to do that. I still like that he wanted to add some info about the topic. Maybe a mod could transform this post to a comment.